# Why can't I run the OpenGeoSuite on port 80?

Tags: boundless-suite, administration

I'm trying to install the Boundless OpenGeoSuite on a Ubuntu 14.04 system, and I'm following the instructions given at: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/intro/installation/ubuntu/install.html#intro-installation-ubuntu-install

So far I've managed to get the Suite to run on Port 8080.

Now I'm follwoing the instructions given in [After installation](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/intro/installation/ubuntu/postinstall.html#intro-installation-ubuntu-postinstall) to get it to run on Port 80, so my Users can access it by directly entering the URL, and don't need to enter the port number.

I've modified the server.xml, and restarted the tomcat7 service, but I can't get it to run.

Tomcat seems to be running, but is not listening to port 80, when seen by `nstat -tulpn`.

How do I get the Suite to run on Port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why Tomcat cannot bind to Port 80, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450045/why-does-tomcat-work-with-port-8080-but-not-80

Ports lower than 1024 are priviledged ports, and hence need additional efforts for application to bind to them.

The solution in our case, is to go to `/etc/default/tomcat7` and change `#AUTHBIND=no` to `AUTHBIND=yes`